# How to convert image stored in db as hex into visible image

Tags: php, php-7

**Context**
I have access to database. That database contains image data something like `0xFFD8FFE....................09090`

**Problem**

I need those cryptic(hex) data to convert into visual image. I am not being able to find any way.

**I have tried**

```
$image = base64_decode(file_get_contents('img.txt'));
$db_img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagepng($db_img);
```

Here `img.txt` is file name containing the hex data.

**It Doesn't work. How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Is it actually stored as the *text* "0xFF...", or is it actually binary data? Also, base 64 and hex are completely different things… Also PNGs are not JPEGs.

Comment: Actually I haven't saved the data. I just have access to the database and I have the mentioned format of data. I don't know what type(jpg or png) of image it was. The hexa code is stored as `text` in the database.

Comment: So it is literally the letters zero, X, Eff, Eff… you're dealing with, yes?

Comment: hmm, seems like. But here I think 0x is the indication of it's hexa vlaue. There is no letter forward from F except the x at the second position.

Comment: Well, that needs to be clarified. Is whatever you're using to look at that data merely displaying binary data in this format to you, or is it actually those ASCII letters?

Comment: Well, It's exactly same thing as I have posted. I am seeing through my both eyes with my DB client. I have no idea if there is any hidden thing(encryption/decryption) showing me this data to me.

Answer (score 0):

To turn a string like `0xFFD8FFE...09090` into actual binary data, you need to first get rid of the "0x" prefix, which is not part of the actual data, and then do a simply hex → bin conversion:

```
$data   = '0xFFD8FFE...09090';  // maybe from file_get_contents
$binary = hex2bin(substr($data, 2));
```

If you don't know what type of image it is then, the most efficient method to find out is probably the use of [finfo](http://php.net/finfo):

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type  = $finfo->buffer($binary);

header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
echo $binary;
```

There's no need to use gd to reencode the image if `$binary` already is an image. You may want to inspect `$type` here a bit to verify that it's really the kind of file you expect before blindly outputting it.